# How OData works in AspNet MVC without change any code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata

To enable OData after installing the *Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2* package, the only thing to do is add the attribute **EnableQuery** and return **IQueryable**.

If the attribute **EnableQuery** is only metadata, what change in the framework?

I mean, when an request arrive the framework matches the url with the Route Table and then create the controller to manage the request. What does change with OData?

Comment: `"what change in the framework?"` - Well, support for OData was added for one thing.  It's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: @David I mean, how can Odata change the response of my controller withou change any behabior in the framwork?

Comment: Why do you think nothing was changed in the framework?  *OData support was added.*  Then, when you use that attribute, you make use of the framework component(s) which drive that support.  Much in the same way that an `Authorize` attribute uses the framework's support for authorization, the `EnableQuery` attribute uses the framework's support for OData.  The controller action behaves differently because you've *added that behavior* by adding the attribute.

Answer (score 2):

`EnableQueryAttribute` derives from `ActionFilterAttribute`, which means it can affect the result of an action via its `OnActionExecuted` method (called internally by Web API). Take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/src/System.Web.OData/OData/EnableQueryAttribute.cs) to see what `EnableQuery` is really doing.